# How to zip a WordprocessingML folder into readable docx

Tags: xml, compression, markdown, docx

I have been trying to write a simple Markdown -> docx parser/writer, but am completely stuck with the last part, which should be the easiest: i.e. compressing the folder into a .docx that Word, or any other .docx reader, will recognize.

My parser-writer is irrelevant really:  I have this problem if I simply unzip any old Word-produced *.docx and then try to recompress it with the usual compression utilities, giving it the file-ending docx.   Is there some mysterious header I should be adding, or do I need a special OPC compression utility, or what?

I don't so much want a tool that will do this, as to figure out what is supposed to be there.  It seems to be independent of the WordprocessingML specification.

Needless to say I don't know anything about compression.  Everything I can find via Google has to do with fancy utilities you can use in business, but I'm making a little executable that would be GPLd or something, and should work on anything.

Comment: Eric White is exactly right in inferring that I experienced "the most common problem around manually zipping an Open XML document".  The error is already visible in the title of the question: I was compressing a folder containing the material, rather than joining the materials severally into a zip file. It occurs to me I might have guessed this, since of course if you unzip a .docx file, you emphatically don't get a little directory, but files all over the directory you're acting in. Thanks!  --Of course, this means I should get back to the project I mention above ... :)

Answer (score 55):

The most common problem around manually zipping together Open XML documents is that it will not work if you zip the directory instead of the contents.  In other words, the[content_types].xml file, and the word, docProps, and _rels directories need to reside at the root level of the zip file.

Comment: Hi, I am the original poster, but I lost this S.O. account, else I would mark this as the 'right answer'.  You are right that my mistake was to zip the directory that included all the material, thinking I needed the right incantation, form of compression ... some subtlety.  MSWord is quite willing to open the file if I accumulate all relevant files (including wholesale addition of subdirectories like `word` that are themselves at the root level.) to a single zip file. So far I have tried this on OS X without incident.  I will study things more.

Comment: Truly open, self-made docx by WinZip and WinRAR are all readable!

Answer (score 23):

Here are steps to unzip my.docx and re-zip:

```
% mkdir unzipped
% cd unzipped/
% unzip ../my.docx    
% zip -r ../rezipped.docx *
% open ../rezipped.docx
```

Answer (score 3):

The compression algorithm used is "Zip" (Base 64) compression.

7zip seems to offer this, though i have no tested it.

Answer (score 3):

Further to what Mica said, the contents of the ZIP file are organised according to the Open Packaging Convention; cf. [Microsoft's Essentials of the Open Packaging Convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee361919%28office.11%29.aspx).

You can use the .NET  System.IO.Packaging to make and manipulate .docx files; this class is implemented in the Mono project.