# Create a docx using FZIP in Actionscript 3 - Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, air, docx

Hello
I will try my best to explain my problem and I really hope someone can figure out what could be wrong.

**Situation:**

Using the office open XML format by microsoft I was able to create the files needed for a clean Word document. These files are all XML files. What I do is write the XML content to a different bytearray for each file.

I then add the bytearray's to the FZIP library (http://codeazur.com.br/lab/fzip/) and create a docx file using the following code:

```
var zip:FZip = new FZip();
zip.addFile("/_rels/", null, false);
        zip.addFile("/docProps/", null, false);
        zip.addFile("/word/", null, false);

        zip.addFile("[Content_Types].xml", bytContentType, false);
        zip.addFile("/docProps/app.xml", bytApp, false);
        zip.addFile("/docProps/core.xml", bytCore, false);
        zip.addFile("/word/document.xml", bytDocument, false);
        zip.addFile("/word/fontTable.xml", bytFontTable, false);
        zip.addFile("/word/settings.xml", bytSettings, false);
        zip.addFile("/word/webSettings.xml", bytWebSettings, false);
        zip.addFile("/_rels/.rels", bytRels, false);

        var file:File = File.documentsDirectory;
        file = file.resolvePath(folder + ".docx");
        var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
        stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
        zip.serialize(stream);
        stream.close();
```

Ok this creates a new docx file in my documents. If I rename the .docx to .zip and unzip it it will follow the exact structure needed for Word documents (example: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5490354/Screen%20shot%202011-05-08%20at%2019.40.10.png)
In this example "Untitled Document" was originally "Untitled document.docx" (then renamed to .zip and extracted)

So you can see everything works fine **untill...** you try to open the "Untitled document.docx" in Word. It will say the file is corrupt.

**WHAT DOES WORK HOWEVER...** 
After extracting the docx file (like in screenshot) when you select all the files/folders inside the Untitled Document folder and ZIP those, then rename ZIP file to docx (see result: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5490354/Screen%20shot%202011-05-08%20at%2019.44.18.png) it works fine in Word and word reads the file correctly. NOTE: If you try to zip and rename the Untitled Document folder again it will become corrupt again as well.

**So my question**
I hope the description was clear and now I am hoping for someone who knows what could be the problem that the word file is corrupt when zipped using FZIP in actionscript 3 but works fine when you ZIP the files after extracting your corrupt file.

Thanks

Comment: While searching for reason of this... There are a lot of ActionScript zip libraries, you may try another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. It was an honest mistake but an annoying one

```
zip.addFile("/docProps/app.xml", bytApp, false);
```

Should be

```
zip.addFile("docProps/app.xml", bytApp, false);
```

Same on all other addFile elements (the first slash needs to be removed)

Answer (score 2):

This is just a chance suggestion, since I can't follow the code: but is it somehow making a *zipped directory* for you, rather than just zipping together an accumulation of files? It should be the latter. (It does look like what your source is doing, admittedly.)

This makes a big difference as I found out once: see [How to zip a WordprocessingML folder into readable docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514052/) -- in particular the excellent answer of Eric White.

I see that in your image of the result of unzipping `Untitled Document.zip`, there is an *outer directory* also called `Untitled Document`. If you did not make this directory separately, but it emerged from unzipping, then I think *that* may be the trouble.  (Notice that if you just rename a random `.docx` file `.zip` and open it, the bits like `[Content_Types].xml` will be spread out all over the directory that has the zipfile in it, rather than tastefully making a new directory for themselves; so the `.docx` file isn't itself a zipped directory.) Another way of putting the point is, if you rename `Archive.docx` to `Archive.zip`, and unzip, does it overwrite the files in the directory, or make a new directory? If Word opens it, assume it's the former.