# How to convert xml to docx in R

Tags: r, xml

I have a `docx` file converted to  bundle of `xml` files in a folder. After modifying some contents of the XML, I want to convert it back to `docx` file. Is it possible to do something like this?

Code for extracting the `XML` from `docx`

```
library(xml2)
library(zip)


unzip("sample.docx", exdir = "test")

doc <- xml2::read_xml("test/word/document.xml")

nodes <- xml2::xml_find_all(doc, "//w:p")


#Modifying the content of xml 
xml2::xml_text(nodes[11]) <- "XML"
```

*To try run the code, you can use any docx file.*

**Question**
How to convert it back to a single `.docx`?

Trying to zip these xml then convert it into a word would that be an option. I don't how to do it but I'm just pointing out. Thanks for the help

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data?

Comment: you can choose any docx to work on it.

Comment: Simply reverse what you did to get the document.xml. Zip all the relevant XML files and then change extension to `.docx`.

Comment: @Parfait I did this and when I opened it showed `word found unreadable content in your_word_file.docx`. Then propmted "yes" and it showed "word experiened an error trying to open the file"

Comment: Did you zip the underlying contents or the whole folder? You need to do the former not latter. So, select all XML and subfolders and zip that all to single file to be renamed to docx. Otherwise use cmd or powershell for zipping. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5751687/1422451). But if you made other changes, then the format may not work.

Comment: I did the latter

Comment: That worked. Thanks alot